# Quartz Scheduler - Updating only the JobDataMap, between jobs

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a Quartz Job that I can schedule with some Cron Trigger.

```
ReportSchedule reportSchedule = ... // my object
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(reportSchedule.getScheduleName(), 
                                    reportSchedule.getScheduleGroup(),
                                    ExtendedReportJob.class /* my job */);

jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("reportSchedule", reportSchedule);
jobDetail.setDescription(reportSchedule.getScheduleDescription());
CronTrigger trigger = ...; // depends on the report schedule 

scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

This code successfully writes the job and details to a **database**.

The `reportSchedule` object contains specific parameters that are required for the job. However, I may want to change the parameters.

I can do this with

```
scheduler.deleteJob(name, group);
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger); 
// where jobDetail.getJobDataMap() has the updated reportSchedule
```

Doing this, however, will trigger the job right away since the trigger depends on the report schedule and I don't want to change it (I want to keep original date). So my question: Is there any way to modify the `JobDetail` or `JobDataMap` between jobs without changing the `Trigger`?

I'm using Quartz 1.6.0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is simple enough, just have to know the API.

The `Scheduler` class has the following method

```
Scheduler#addJob(JobDetail, boolean);
```

In which the passed `JobDetail` will overwrite the previous one if the `boolean` argument is set to `true`.

So

```
// name and group are the primary key of the job detail
final JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(name, group, ExtendedReportJob.class);

// reportSchedule is the object I've previously modified
jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put(ORStatics.REPORT_SCHEDULE, reportSchedule);
jobDetail.setDescription(reportSchedule.getScheduleDescription());

// overwrite the previous job, however retaining the triggers       
scheduler.addJob(jobDetail, true);
```

will update the job detail in persistent storage. Since the primary key for the table containing the `JobDetail` will remain the same, we don't need to change the triggers. They will still execute it as scheduled.

Comment: For this to work the job needs to be durable, otherwise an exception will be thrown, by default new jobs are not durable so it will need to be set by calling `.storeDurably(true)` on the `JobBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

What about getting the trigger with `getTrigger(String triggerName, String triggerGroup)` and store it in a variable. Then create a new job with your new jobDataMap and use the old trigger?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did at first. However, when you schedule a new job, it does some computation that changes the NextFireTime on the trigger and in my case it would set it in the past, thereby re-triggering it. I'm going to post my solution later today.